# Why does the filename contain question marks when I run a script on my remote machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sftp

I have a tiny script that simply fetches the current date, runs a PHP script and redirect the output (and errors) to a filename containing the current date.

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
FILE="log/${DATE}.log"
php -q script.php >> $FILE 2>&1
```

When I run this script on my local machine (Windows 7, Aptana IDE), the PHP script works fine and the logfile has the expected filename, e.g. `20140502.log`.

But when I push that script via SFTP to my remote machine and execute that script, the filename looks like this:

```
20140502?.log?
```

What might be the problem? Is this an enconding error (e.g. encoding for SFTP uploads is ANSII, where UTF-8 is expected)? Or do I have to change anything in the script itself?

Information about system/shell:

```
[foo@bar path]$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Funny fact: If that script is called by a cronjob, the question marks don't occur. Only if I manually run the script.

Comment: Usually the `?` indicates that a character cannot be displayed. Certainly sounds like an encoding difference. Can you give us the output of `env|grep -E '(LC|LANG)'`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Output is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I meant the output on both ends.

Comment: Sorry for missing that... Unfortunately this command doesn't output anything on Windoze :/

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel  Dont use capital names for variables. Also the easiest thing to do would be: `filename="log/$(date +%Y%m%d).log"`

Comment: Yes it does, you just need to know where to look... The default culture for Windows is ISO8859-WESTERN, which is not UTF-8 Compliant, Control Panel - Region and Language.  See [this manifesto](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) i didnt write it...

Comment: Are you aware that this sequence of redirections (`2>&1 >> $FILE`) sends stderr to the terminal and stdout to the file? If you want stderr to go to the file as well, you need `>> $FILE 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably have some non-printable characters on end of lines (eg. CRLF from Windows), run:

```
cat -A scriptname
```

on remote machine, it'll show you all characters in your script.
Then, you can convert to unix-like format running

```
dos2unix scriptname
```

Answer (score 3):

Found Notepad ++ to be very useful for correcting this after attempting the answer

> cat -A scriptname>
>   dos2unix scriptname

as this still presented errors when trying to convert.

Through Notepad ++ there's the option in the edit menu/EOL Conversion/Unix/OSX Format.

Still very much a learner but this method solved my problem, however the previous solution assisted in finding where the problem was.